# Как делается реверс строки (void arrayReverse)?

Tags: c, массивы

Написать функцию:

```
void arrayReverse(int array[], int size)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все уже описанное - для C++, для чистого С писать функцию ручками, типа этой:

```
void arrayReverse(int array[], int size) {
   int i, temp;
   for (i = 0, size--; i < size; i++, size--) {
      temp = array [i];
      array[i] = array [size];
      array[size] = temp;
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Классический способ - переставить в кортежах вида `(1, n)` элементы местами, например, с помощью `std::swap`. *Т.е вам необходимо пробежаться по парам `(1, n)`, `(2, n - 1)`, ... и применить к ним этот самый `std::swap`.*

Понятно, что в случае, если массив нечетного размера, то центральный элемент должен остаться на месте.

*С кодом, я думаю, вы справитесь самостоятельно.*

Answer (score 2):

Есть разные варианты, например, с помощью рекурсии (не самый эффективный способ)

```
void arrayReverse(int *a, int l) {
    if (l > 1) {
        swap(&a[0], &a[l - 1]);
        arrayReverse(++a, l - 2);
    }
}
```

где функция swap меняет местами два значения в массиве.

Comment: Куда уж проще... swap(x, y) - это x на место y, а y на место x.

Comment: Если можно еще какой то метод посоветуйте.

Comment: Интересно, конечно, но попробуйте таким способом зареверсить массив длиной `10e6`, если предположить, что `tail-рекурсия` не соптимизится.

Comment: а без функции swap можно обойтись?

Comment: @arcs_host В `C` нешаблонный `swap` для `int` можно написать как `int t = a; a = b; b = t;`. В `C++` можно написать свой шаблонный `swap` или воспользоваться `std::swap`.

Comment: Естественно без рекурсии. Просто в цикле по i от 0 до size/2 меняете местами array[i] с array[size-1-i]. Как менять см. выше.

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
void arrayReverse(int array[], int size) {
     int *a, *b, i;
     for(a = array, b = array+size-1, i=0; i < size/2; i++) {
         *a ^= *b;
         *b ^= *a;
         *a++ ^= *b--;
     }
}
```

Comment: По рукам надо бить за `xor'инг` вместо свапа в продакшене.

Comment: @alexlz Оптимизировать, так до конца.

    
    register int *a = array;
    register int *b = array+size-1;
    while (a < b) { ...

Далее, как у Вас.

Или Ваш ответ это не попытка экономии 4-х байт в стеке ?

Comment: Давайте объявим конкурс на самое извращенное написание простейшей функции )))

Comment: С условием `a < b` согласен, ну а с `register` компилятор сам разберётся. Ну задачи сверхоптимизации не ставил. @котик: а чем xor нехороши? Мне интересно стало.

Comment: А еще можно вместо 

i<size/2;

написать

i<(size >> 1);

На самом деле, оптимизации не будет, поскольку битовые операции производятся медленнее, чем простое присвоение значений.

Кроме того, последняя строчка

*a++ ^= *b--;

отдает большой неопределенностью. Такие игры с инкриментами/декриментами стоит избегать

Comment: @mikillskegg: во-первых, это компилятор и сам должен сообразить. Во-вторых, как указал @avp, `i` -- вообще лишняя деталь.

Comment: Сообразить что? Не надо полагаться на компилятор. Их поведение часто непредсказуемо.

Comment: Насчет экономии это была шутка не про **i**, а про **t** - когда обмен без xor, через переменную. 

Ну а если экономить хотим, а по рукам боимся, то в качестве **t** можно использовать **size** (все равно он в стеке). А насчет быстродействия и проч. запустим gcc -O3 -S и посмотрим...

Comment: Вариант, конечно, с теоретической точки зрения интересный, говорит об изобретательности автора и пытливости его мысли. Но, безусловно, не для практического применения )))

Comment: @alexlz Ну в ответе на вопрос - это можно. Но если бы вы в проекте написали `swap` для целых чисел с помощью `xor`, который, **очевидно, плохо читается,** и не факт, что работает быстрее *(зная современные компиляторы)* - то перед нами случай `premature optimization`. 

--------

Стало непонятно, а пользы 0, т.к, чтобы сваппинг элементов стал `hotspot'ом` приложения, это еще надо постараться.

Comment: Увы, на 386+ с `xor`ами команд получается больше. Ну их... Просто идиома очень уж старая (как экскременты мамонта)
@mikillskegg: а вот с автоинкрементами/декрементами никакой неопределённости быть не может. Как в стандарте написано, так и должно работать. Порядок задан жёстко.