# Написать реверс части массива от a до b включительно.

Tags: c, алгоритм

```
void sliceReverse(int array[], int start, int end) {
    if ( start < end ) {
        int first = array[start];

        for ( int i = start; i < end; i++ ) {
            first = array[i];
            array[i] = array[end];
        }
        array[end] = first;
    }
}
```

Не могу разобрать, что делаю не так. Дайте подсказку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Попробуйте проговорить вслух**, что сейчас делает ваш код. Мне кажется, вы сразу поймете, что именно вы делаете не так.

Реверс части массива, как вы понимаете, делается почти столь же просто, как и реверс всего массива, о котором вы уже спрашивали [**здесь.**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/47040/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-void-arrayreverse)

Вообще говоря, `sliceReverse(array, start, end) = arrayReverse(array + start, end - start + 1)` *(или `end - start` в зависимости от того, как выбрана конвенция определения `end`)*. Отсюда финальный код для решения задачи получается очень просто.

Comment: Так это он тот вопрос задавал? Не пошло в прок. Ничему не научился...

Comment: Может, и научится...

Answer (score 2):

Немножко подшаманил и получилось вот такое :

```
void sliceReverse(int array[], int start, int end) {
   int temp;

    for ( ; start < end; start++, end-- ) {
        temp = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;
    }
}
```

Спасибо также за предыдущие комментарии.

Answer (score 1):

Все неправильно. Лучше дам готовый код, а ты его разбери

```
void sliceReverse(int array[], int start, int end) {
if ( start >= end ) return;
    int temp;
    for ( ; start < end; start++, end-- ) {
        temp = array[start];
        array[start] = array[end];
        array[end] = temp;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Кстати, кто минусовал, объясните почему.

Comment: А зачем после if, return ?

Comment: Если начал идет после конца, оканчиваем функцию, поскольку дальнейшие разговоры с ней бесполезны.

Comment: Да, можно без проверок. Цикл завершится, не начавшись.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так ( может где небольшие помарки - проверить не успел):

```
    void sliceReverse(int array[], int start, int end) {
        while (start < end ) {
            int tmp = array[start];
            array[start] = array[end];
            array[end] = tmp;
            ++start;
            --end;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Переменную temp лучше объявлять перед циклом.

Comment: Можете объяснить почему?

Comment: При начале каждой новой итерации будет выделяться память под эту переменную в стеке, а в конце - "удаляться". Потом опять выделяться и т.д. Будет выполняться бессмысленная лишняя работа, замедляющая программу. Лучше один раз выделить память и уже к ней каждый раз обращаться.

Comment: @mikillskegg Несогласен, кстати. Код все равно соптимизится, а в случае объявления ее в цикле мы следуем правилу **"объявлять переменные как можно ближе к области использования".**

Comment: Не надо надеяться на компиляторы. Может, соптимизируется, а может - нет. Лучше сразу писать нормально. А расположение будет и так уж ближе некуда.

Comment: 1) Согласен с @Котик_хочет_кушать
2) Автоматические переменные "умирают" при выходе из блока, то-есть после выполнения цикла.

Comment: @mikillskegg Не знаю, всегда программировал по принципу *"напиши хороший читаемый код",* а дальше, **если нужно,** то оптимизируй. В этом примере, конечно, читаемость не сильно пострадала, но если каждый раз оптимизировать такие временные переменные, то читаемости кода это точно повредит.

Comment: Так мне кажется, оптимизация важнее "читаемости", которая, вообще-то, штука относительная: одним одно легче читать, другим другое. Может, конечно, преимущество оптимизации перед всем остальным у меня профессиональное.. Тут, конечно, надо разумно ко всему подходить.

Comment: @mikillskegg Хм, у меня есть пример пары проектов, когда страсть к преждевременной оптимизации людей, которые над ними работала, привела почти к полному фиаско. Другое дело, что применительно к `OpenMP`, `CUD'е` и `OpenCL` ваш подход, конечно, имеет намного больше смысла, и в этом случае вы правы.

Comment: По поводу места для объявления temp. Не знаю, как все компиляторы, а gcc для **всех** подобных переменных выделяет место в стеке **один раз** при входе в функцию. Память части из них (если они в разных блоках) будет перекрываться.

Answer (score 1):

Логику построения цикла не понятна.
Вы каждый раз перезаписываете first, при это его не используете.
По этому циклу у вас везде запишется последний элемент.
Я бы сделал так:

```
   int i, j, buf;
    for (i = start, j = end; i < j; ++i, --j ) 
    {
        buf = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = buf;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Подсказка:

start и end должны двигаться **друг к другу** пока не сравняются.

Между адресуемыми ими элементами массива производите обмен.